# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add/remove the active class from the data-filer = variable, but this error gives:
[Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: li[data-filter=.arroz-1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cPL1.png)

```
$('li[data-filter=' + xNew + ']').addClass("active");
$('li[data-filter=' + xOld + ']').removeClass("active");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `li[data-filter=.arroz-1]` - don't use a period in the name of your data attributes. I noticed this throws a script error in jquery

Comment: @kinglish This point is part of the variable, I just marked it as an example. It is necessary in the case in question, and it is not error, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed some apostrophe. Try this:

```
$("li[data-filter='" + xNew + "']").addClass("active");
$("li[data-filter='" + xOld + "']").removeClass("active");
```